# How do I add to a list in another file in python using Pickle?

Tags: python, list, append, pickle

I have been trying to append to a list inside of another file, I also am trying to make it so if it has more than 3 variables inside of it, it deletes the oldest added variable and adds the new data, it confuses me pretty badly and this is the code I have so far:

```
with open ("TestScores_Class1.txt","ab") as a:
    Class1Score = [name, points]
    Class1Scorelen = (Class1Score,a)
    if len(Class1Scorelen) > 3:
        del (Class1Score,a)[3]
    pickle.dump(Class1Score,a)
    a.close()
```

Comment: You don't need `a.close()` when you use `with`, it is explicitly taken care off.

Comment: You should probably be using `pickle.load` or `pickle.loads` at some point. How else can you see what items the file already contains?

Answer (score 1):

Try to break your program up into small logical segments. You're trying to do three things:

- load a list from file
- modify a list
- save a list to file

Clearly separating each action should simplify things.

```
import pickle

to_add = ("Kevin", 42)

#Open the file and read its contents. 
#If the file is blank or doesn't exist, make an empty list.
try:
    with open("my_file.txt") as file:
        data = pickle.load(file)
except (EOFError, IOError):
    data = []

#add the item to the list. Shorten the list if it's too long.
data.append(to_add)
if len(data) > 3:
    data = data[-3:]

#Overwrite the file with the new data.
with open("my_file.txt", "w") as file:
    pickle.dump(data, file)
```

Comment: You don't need the `if len(data) > 3:` check.